# self.client.login does not stay logged in for duration of test

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-testing

I have functionality that I want to test that allows the user to add records on the home page and later view
the records in the saved page - which works when running the app.

When running the test below initially the user is logged in but when the browser url is pointed to /saved
the user has turned into an AnonymousUser.

Is there a reason for this? Here is my code below.

Test:

```
def test_viewing_logged_in_users_saved_records(self):

    # A user logs in
    self.client.login(username = 'testuser1', email='testuser1@test.com', password = 'testuser1password')
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)

    # set up our POST data - keys and values are strings
    # and post to home URL
    response = self.client.post('/',
                                {'title': TestCase3.title
                                 })

    # The user is redirected to the new unit test display page
    self.assertRedirects(response, 'unittestcase/hLdQg28/')

    # Proceeds to the page where they can see their saved records
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/saved')

    # The user can view the tests that they have saved
    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn(TestCase3.title, body.text)
```

View:

```
def home_post(request):
    logging.warning('In home_post') 
    logging.warning(request.user) 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
    ....

def saved(request):
    logging.warning('In saved')
    logging.warning(request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
    ....
```

Logging:

```
WARNING:root:In home_post
WARNING:root:testuser1

WARNING:root:In saved
WARNING:root:AnonymousUser
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first post request to the home url uses the dummy client, which you have logged in.

Your request to the `/saved` url uses `self.browser`, which is not logged in.

It is not clear why you are using both `self.client` and `self.browser` in the same test. If you don't need to use the live server in this test, then I would use `self.client` throughout. For the example you've shown, you could do:

```
response = self.client.get('/saved')
self.assertContains(response, TestCase3.title)
```

If you do need to use the live server, see the [live server test case docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#liveservertestcase) for an example of logging in using the selenium client.

Comment: thanks, it was a bit of Django noobie confusion about logging in that led to using both in the same test, its working now!